# Is there a way of "chunking" drake outputs to speed up plan verification and display?

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I'm conducting simulations over a range of models and parameter values. At this point in time my `drake` workflow involves over 3k thousand simulated `data.frames` and corresponding `stanfit` objects.

Trying to run `make` currently incurs a delay of ~2 minutes before plan execution begins. I assume that this is because `drake` is going through its cache to verify which steps in the plan will need updating. I would like to have some way of letting it know that it can represent all of these models as a single monolithic chunk of output. What I could do is make a function that writes all my output objects as a side-effect and then outputs a hash of sorts so that `drake` is "fooled" as to what needs to be checked but I can't restructure my code at this point in time given an upcoming deadline and the processing time involved.

Similarly, for purposes of using the dependency graph, having 3k+ objects show up makes it unusable. It would be nice to be able to collapse certain objects under a single "output type" group.

Comment: Just curious: what version of `drake` are you using? Version 6.2.1 just arrived on CRAN, and it is faster.

Comment: I'm on 6.1 but I literally need to hand in my thesis by tomorrow so I'm not risking it at this point. :)

Comment: Gosh, it's really crunch time! Best of luck! I think the best solution on your tight timeline is just to set `verbose` to `4` to get more frequent progress updates. Maybe that and `make(console_log_file = "my_log.txt")`.

Comment: Version 6.2.1 should theoretically not invalidate your targets. (As [these release notes describe](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/master/NEWS.md#version-620), most of the changes are about increasing speed and reducing dependencies.) But it may not be wise to bet your thesis on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I know what you are saying, and I think about this problem all the time. In fact, trying to get rid of the delay is one of my top two priorities for `drake` for 2019.

Unfortunately, `drake` does not have a solution right now that will allow you to keep your targets up to date. The long-term solution will probably be speed improvements + https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/304 + https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/233. These are important areas of development, but also huge undertakings.

For new projects, you could have each target be a list of fitted `stan` models.

```
drake_plan(
  data1 <- generate_data(...),
  data2 <- generate_data(...),
  models_data1 <- fit_models(data1),
  models_data2 <- fit_models(data2)
)

fit_models <- function(data){
  list(
    run_stan(data, "normal_priors"),
    run_stan(data, "t_priors")
  )
}
```

And for the graph visualizations, there is support for target clusters. See https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/vis.html#clusters

## EDIT: parallel computing and verbosity

If you run `make(jobs = c(imports = 4, targets = 6))`, `drake` will use 4 processes on your local machine to do the preprocessing. And `make(verbose = 4)` shows more progress messages than with the default setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Wouldn't all the stanfits have to be in memory at some point for the list approach to work? I don't think this would go smoothly given the number and size of simulations I'm running.

Comment: Yes they would, so it's a balancing act. Another idea: split up your plan into sub-plans and run those sub-plans with different caches (https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/store.html). Also seems like the sort of thing you would want to wait to try until you had a new project.